# Having issues getting the post tags to display in archive page - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, tags

I am using jnews as a theme and a "block" template feeds the look of my page located here

https://theseeker.ca/category/lifestyle/

where the category displays, on the picture, I want to display the tags instead and I tried everything I could possibly think of, to no avail.  This is the code and in bold, what I want to replace with tags.

```
<?php
/**
 * @author : Jegtheme
 */
namespace JNews\Module\Block;

class Block_37_View extends BlockViewAbstract {

    public function render_block_type_1( $post, $image_size ) {
        $post_id         = $post->ID;
        $box_shadow_flag = isset( $this->attribute['box_shadow'] ) && $this->attribute['box_shadow'] ? 'box_shadow' : '';
        $permalink       = get_the_permalink( $post );
    
        

        return '<article ' . jnews_post_class( 'jeg_post ' . $box_shadow_flag, $post_id ) . ">
                    <div class='box_wrap'>
                        <div class=\"jeg_thumb\">
                            " . jnews_edit_post( $post_id ) . "
                            <a href=\"{$permalink}\">{$this->get_thumbnail($post_id, $image_size)}</a>
                            
**# <div class=\"jeg_post_category\">
#                               <span>{$this->get_primary_category($post_id)}</span>
#                           </div>**
                        </div>
                        <div class=\"jeg_postblock_content\">
                            <h3 class=\"jeg_post_title\">
                                <a href=\"{$permalink}\">" . get_the_title( $post ) . "</a>
                            </h3>
                            {$this->post_meta_1($post)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>";
    }
```

How am I supposed to achieve that?

get_the_tags function triggers a critical error

Answer (score 1):

Which critical error do you get?

Have you passed Post Id or Object to the get_the_tags function?

```
    $posttags = get_the_tags($post_id);
    if ($posttags) {
      foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        echo $tag->name . ' '; 
      }
    }
```